# Add a page to Next.js with Webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

Is there a way to generate a file dynamically and inject it into `/pages` without saving it in this directory?

For example, if I'd like to create a Next.js plugin that adds `example.com/build` static page with timestamp of last compilation, or list file structure of the project.